# Cesium JS Globe Tilt constraint

Tags: 3d, webgl, data-visualization, 3d-modelling, cesiumjs

How would I set a constraint for the rotation/tilt of the 3D globe so that I don't end up staring at the north / south pole... however way I mouse-drag.

Or is there a way to listen in and tilt the globe back gently such that the north/south poles will always eventually end up 'vertical'?

(I'm using version b26)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are experiencing is the camera's `constrainedAxis`.  By default, both CesiumWidget and Viewer set `constrainedAxis` to `Cartesian3.UNIT_Z`.  This keeps the globe oriented north and prevents the earth from rotating to an unfamiliar view.  While this is subjective behavior, in the past we found many people preferred it (we may change it again in the future if enough people disagree).  The good news is that it's easy to change at any time by just assigning `constrainedAxis` to be `undefined`.  If you have a handle to the current scene, you can simple do: `scene.camera.constrainedAxis = undefined;`

Comment: I got it. It is scene.camera.controller.constrainedAxis

Comment: Hey Matthew... I was switching back and forth 2d/3d morph and could eventually produce this error each time I tested for b26:

An error occurred while rendering.  Rendering has stopped. RangeError: Invalid array length
RangeError: Invalid array length
    at Y (.../cesium/Cesium.js?body=1:396:8829)
    at Z (.../cesium/Cesium.js?body=1:396:10706)
    at lt.render (.../cesium/Cesium.js?body=1:396:17895)
    at D.render (.../cesium/Cesium.js?body=1:401:15149)
    at D.render (.../cesium/Cesium.js?body=1:403:10806)
    at t (.../cesium/Cesium.js?body=1:403:3824)

Comment: To be sure - I could replicate the rendering error on both the default scenemodepicker as well as the custom buttons I have that call the morph methods.